# Cant convert JSON to csv by jq

Tags: node.js, jq, json2csv

I am new to jq,  I have a JSON file from (call: all.2):

```
{"code":0, "data": {"date": 1617978312600,"ticker": {"KAVAUSDT": {"vol": "15022.96236047","low": "7.0419","open":"7.8990","high": "8.1997","last": "7.1516","buy": "7.1516","buy_amount":"11.02402741","sell":"7.1699","sell_amount": "37.46319593"},"CFXUSDT": {"vol": "108550.36674746","low": "1.226636","open": "1.267724","high": "1.378400","last": "1.273187","buy": "1.272200","buy_amount": "14.65071234","sell": "1.294900","sell_amount": "84.88000789"},"SUSHIBTC": {"vol": "5644.10352324","low": "0.00024680","open": "0.00024857","high": "0.00026493","last": "0.00025704","buy": "0.00025563","buy_amount": "104.74291100","sell": "0.00025730","sell_amount": "94.16400000"},"SUNUSDT": {"vol": "7058.81491709","low":"37.3431","open":"37.9590","high": "44.0446","last": "40.6945","buy": "40.1001","buy_amount": "25.40000000","sell":"41.0771","sell_amount": "3.40000000"}}}, "message": "OK"}
```

I want to convert the data to csv ( space separated) similar to the following:
[As Shown in the ATTACHED IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC2Xi.png)

I tried  the following, but it didnt work:

```
mlr --j2c cat all.2>allq1.csv

jq -r '.[]|[ .ticker,.ticker.vol,.ticker.low,.ticker.open,.ticker.high,.ticker.last,.ticker.buy,.ticker.buy_amount,.ticker.sell,.ticker.sell_amount ]|@csv' all.2 > all.csv
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. As per the [mcve] guidelines, it would be helpful if you could include the text of the expected output to facilitate verification of putative solutions.  An image, though possibly helpful in some ways, is insufficient for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
jq -r '.data.ticker | to_entries[] | [.key, (.value | (.vol|tonumber), (.low|tonumber))] | @csv'
```

Explanation: `.data.ticker` - path to your data, `to_entries[]` - since ticker name is key, we need to convert this object to `.key` and `.value`, `()` - parenthesis helps, so you don't need to write full path every time, `tonumber` - convert string to number (remove double quotes)

Add all your fields